# gcc compiler doesn't recognize my code for using Serial Port in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c++, gcc, raspberry-pi

I'm compiling and running a C++/OpenCV program directly on the Raspberry Pi 3's Terminal with the line:

g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`  name.cpp      -o name

I have been working like this without issues, but now I want to send some results like coordinates and numbers via serial port to Arduino, I tried to use this code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

//######################################################################

int fd = open("/dev/ttyAMS0", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
  perror("/dev/ttyAMS0");
  return 1;
}

struct termios tios;
tcgetattr(fd, &tios);
// disable flow control and all that, and ignore break and parity errors
tios.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;
tios.c_oflag = 0;
tios.c_lflag = 0;
cfsetspeed(&tios, B9600);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &tios);

// the serial port has a brief glitch once we turn it on which generates a
// start bit; sleep for 1ms to let it settle
usleep(1000);    

// output to serial port
char msg[] = "hi there";
write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));
```

But now each time I try to compile I get the errors shown in the image [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qOJL.jpg):

[image: error]

So I guess I'm missing something, I have added all the libraries for the Serial Port as well but I don't know if I should add something on the line for compile as I did with the opencv libraries. Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Currently, you aren't showing us your code, so we aren't really able to help you. Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, now I have added just the Serial Port Code which still gives me the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add comment so I will answer what I think about your problem.
Looks like your code written in global scope outer any function body.

You can't use if statement out of any function body.
Try to enclose your if statement in function body.

Something like this:

```
void chec(int fd) {
  if (fd == -1) {
     perror("/dev/ttyAMS0");
     exit(1);
  }
}
int fd = open("/dev/ttyAMS0", O_RDWR);
check(fd);
```

Comment: Oh my bad! You are absolutely right! with all the previous code I had I didn't realize I was putting this part of code outside of any of my functions, I moved it into the one I wanted and it is all fixed now, thanks! :D